# The upload key is the same as the deployment key. For security reasons we need them to be different. Please use a different upload certificate

Tags: android, google-play

The upload key is the same as the deployment key. For security reasons we need them to be different. Please use a different upload certificate.

I am getting this error while generating the keys.

How can I  fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what an "upload key" is and what a "deployment key" is. Please also explain, **in detail**, what "this error" is and explain how you are "generating the keys".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you already uploaded the sign key for production or for testing and You're trying to upload the same key for production release.
There's two option select another key and upload it but test users need to reinstall the app.
Or continue with current key which is the same key you want to upload and you've already uploaded for production or for alpha/beta testing.
If you notice under `Releases signed by Google Play` is written

`Google will use your chosen app siging key to sign your releases`

instead of

`Google will generate and protect an app siging key for your releases`

So google will use your own signing key to sign the app.

Answer (score 1):

The .perm file simply means you will save it to a new file which will be in .pem format so you can use any name which is not "certicate.pem"

For example you can run it as "keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file mykey.pem"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are attempting to use the new [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) feature to allow the Google Play Developer Console to sign your APKs that you upload instead of signing them yourself.

This error message means that the signing key you are attempting to use for *uploading* builds is the same as the one you are attempting to tell the Google Play Developer Console to use to *sign* builds. The two cannot be the same.

Make sure you are following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) as appropriate for whether you have a new or existing app.

Comment: i dont understand your answer

Comment: This answer is incorrect as I have tested this in 3 diff Google Play Developer accounts, seems like a bug as the certificates were totally diff as they were generated separately